# Can't distribute app in b2b, option disabled. What am i missing?

Tags: ios, b2b

i have developed and uploaded an ios app into the App Store Connect. The app is going to be used only within our company. 
I should select "Available for private distribution to specific organizations..." option but it's disabled (greyed out). In January i published 2 apps in same way and i was able to select the b2b option. 
Now that option is greyed out and i have no idea what's different this time. Obviously all agreement (taxing..etc) signed as i already published 2 apps in January. Also the app is free, selected country is UK, everything filled as with the other apps. 
I am sure i am missing something but can't work out what's that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple gave the answer in email:
“Available for private distribution to specific organizations on Apple Business Manager or Apple School Manager” option is available only if you've agreed to the latest iOS Paid Apps contract even when your app is free."